# Determining the degrees of freedom from 'chisq' result in ROCR package

Tags: r, roc, chi-squared

Forgive me for what perhaps may be a simply question. I am relatively new to statistics and R, for that matter.

I am currently performing multiple logistic regression on the following model: E6~S+FA+FR+DV. Where the dependent variable E6 is dichotomous(0,1) and S, FA and FR are ordinal categorical independent variables with scales of 0:7, 1:3 and 1:5 respectively. DV is a dichotomous independent variable (0,1).

As a measure of performance I am currently using the ROCR package in R. Where I have created a prediction object and am then proceeding to produce a performance object using the measure 'chisq' for evaluating the models fit by test of independence.

This is all working fine and I receive the X2 value for the model fit, however the Degrees of Freedom(DF) are not returned. I should mention that the model has 4110 observations.

Is there a simple way of determining the DF for X2 for the above mentioned model. For example, is there a reason why ROCR returns the X2 value, but not the DF?

Any guidance would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've flagged to move to CV.

Comment: @Alex Did you raise a moderator flag? There is a close reason that indicates a migration to [stats.se] is appropriate (off-topic...other site...CV). It would probably be better to use that than a flag.

Comment: @MrFlick I raised migration

Comment: @Ryan, If your end goal is to get a p-value for *goodness of fit* for the model you described, then you don't need to use the `ROCR` package. You can try the base `chisq.test()` function.

Comment: @nerajt - thanks for the comment. I have used chisq.test() - however I am unsure why the chisq option is provided as a measure with ROCR and the DF is not provided?

Comment: @neerajt - Sorry misspelled your name. The usefulness of the ROCR in this case is the fact that I can pass a measure of "chisq" to a list of lists containing predictions from a 10 fold cross validation. So I wanted to get a goodness of fit for each model fitted to each fold and produce an average.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I still think you can achieve that without ROCR<sup>*</sup>. I can't comment on why ROCR isn't returning degrees of freedom, but I can tell you that for your dichotomous labels, the degrees of freedom will be 1. If you're curious about why, check out this [khan academy video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/statistics-inferential/chi-square/v/contingency-table-chi-square-test)

* *Don't get me wrong, I think ROCR is awesome for visualizing ROC curves and choosing thresholds and stuff.*

Comment: @neerajt  - Thanks for the clarification,I did think that was DF=1 was correct, but when you interrogate the glm model the DF>3000 so it totally confused me. I accept that I do not know enough about the statistical method actually.